# Can I use html color picker (type=color input) but apply it only when user clicks another button?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function startup() {
       colorPicker = document.querySelector("#color-picker");
       colorPicker.addEventListener("input", chg_btncolor, false);
}
function chg_btncolor(event) {
       color-selected == event.target.value
       contact-info-btn.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
            contact-info-btn.style.backgroundColor == color-selected;
       })  
}
```

```html
<label for="color-picker">Color:</label>
<input type="color" id="color-picker" />
<form method="post" class="homepg-form" id="homepg-form" >
        .
        .
        .
<button class="contact-info-btn" id="contact-info-btn" type="button" >İletişim bilgileri</button>
```

I am trying to use the standard html `<input type=color>` element color picker to change the background color of a button that I click but I can't get it to work.

When the window loads, I call 'startup' function In my code to check for the color picker input event. if a color is selected from the color picker, I call function 'chg_btncolor'. In this function I check if 'contact-info-btn' button is clicked and if so I set it's background color to the selected color. But it doesn't work.

It looks like both the color picker input event and the button click event together might be causing a problem and 'event.target.value' doesn't have the right value that I am expecting. But I don't know how else to do it. I will appreciate any help that might solve my problem.

Comment: Please show us a proper [mre] of what you are talking about, instead of giving us a vague and ambiguous verbal explanation only.

Comment: _"It looks like I need to figure out why I am getting this message, first."_ - sounds like the button you clicked was a _submit_ button within a form, but you neglected to properly suppress the button click default action in your click event handler. If you do not have a proper endpoint to process a POST request from this form though, then the question would be, why is it a form in the first place, and/or why are the buttons _submit_ buttons.

Comment: My question has been closed. I have edited it and added my html and cs code. Please open it again. Thanks.

Comment: Multiple things wrong here. You need to pass a function _reference_ to `addEventListener`, but you are _calling_ your functions in those places. (If you need to pass parameters, you need to wrap the whole thing into an anonymous function.) And trying to add a window load handler from _inside_ a click handler, makes really little sense - what would you be clicking on, if the window had not already loaded? It is not going to fire another load event later on.

Comment: Thanks CBroe. The 'can not post /' problem has been fixed thanks to your comment. It was stupid of me not to think about it. I have no other way of passing the clicked button id as a parameter so I did it this way. I welcome any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var colorSelected; // Declare a global variable to store the selected color

function startup() {
    var colorPicker = document.querySelector("#color-picker");
    var contactInfoBtn = document.querySelector("#contact-info-btn");

    // Listen for color changes on the color picker
    colorPicker.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
        colorSelected = event.target.value; // Store the selected color
    }, false);

    // Add click event listener to the button
    contactInfoBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){ 
        if (colorSelected) {
            contactInfoBtn.style.backgroundColor = colorSelected; // Set the button color
        }
    });
}

// Call startup when the window loads
window.onload = startup;
```

```html
<label for="color-picker">Color:</label>
    <input type="color" id="color-picker" />
    <form method="post" class="homepg-form" id="homepg-form" >
    .
    .
    .
    <button class="contact-info-btn" id="contact-info-btn" type="button" >İletişim bilgileri</button>
```

use a global variable to store the selected color from an color picker. This variable is updated whenever the color picker's value changes. a click event listener is added to a button, which changes the button's background color to the stored color when clicked,

Comment: You saved my life, thanks. Now it works like a charm. It looks like I still have a long way to go to become a skilled js developer.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a global variable and you can even do with only 1 event handler. You can do this by retrieving the color picker value when pressing the button.

This reduces the amount and complexity of code and increases the readability.

```js
document.querySelector('#contact-info-btn').addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = document.querySelector("#color-picker").value
});
```

```html
<label for="color-picker">Color:</label>
<input type="color" id="color-picker" />
<form method="post" class="homepg-form" id="homepg-form">
  <button class="contact-info-btn" id="contact-info-btn" type="button">İletişim bilgileri</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your method also works, thanks. However, the color change is only good for that session. When I refresh the page, it goes back to the original color. How can I make  it permanent?

Comment: You can make it persistent in many ways, you can store it in the browsers local storage, you can store it in a database on the server, store it in a cookie, etc. What to use depends on your requirements.